# How do I integrate $\int\dfrac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $$\displaystyle\int\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}\,dx$$

In Mathematica:

`Integrate[(E^x - E^-x)/(E^x + E^-x), x]`

I'm using the substitution $u=e^x + e^{-x}$, so
$du = e^x + e^{-x}$
$e^{-x} = u - e^x$
$e^{x} = u - e^{-x}$

Substituting into the the equation gives:

$$\int\frac{2e^x-u}{u}du$$

But I'm not sure where to go from here to get the supposed answer of:

$$\log(1 + e^{2x}) - x$$

Comment: I don't know what kind of anti derivative you are looking for, but essentially you are trying to anti derive a hyperbolic tan which is very easy since the hyperbolic sine is the derivative of the hyperbolic cosine...Just a different way of looking at it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your $du$ is wrong. $du=e^x-e^{-x}dx$

Your integral just becomes $\int \frac1u du$. This becomes $\ln(e^x+e^{-x})+C$. You can use algebra a bit here to get your result.

Answer (score 6):

You have $du$ error. It is $du=(e^x-e^{-x})dx$ so after variable change integrating just $du/u$ which is $\ln(u).$

Answer (score 4):

You made a small mistake, $du$ is actually equal to $e^x-e^{-x}$, so you have $\int \dfrac {du}{u}$

Comment: "You made a small misrake" heh

Comment: @Zachary Selk I am typing on my phone haha

Comment: @ZacharySelk Did you get a notification for the tag in my previous comment? Whenever I try to tag someone on my phone, the name doesn't auto-complete like it does on PC, so I am not sure under what circumstances it works.

Comment: Yeah, I got your notification. I just thought it was ironic.

Answer (score 4):

May be another way $$\int\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}dx=\int\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)}dx=\int\frac{(\cosh(x))'} {\cosh(x)}dx=\log(\cosh(x))+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the denominator $e^x+e^{−x}$ be $t$
then differentiating both sides
$$e^x+e^{−x}$$
$$e^x-e^{−x}=dt/dx \iff (e^x-e^{−x})dx=dt$$

substitute this in the question
$$∫1/t \cdot dt
\log t$$